# Disable features while importing site

Tags: 2010, powershell, sub-site

We have an export of a subsite (using `Export-SPWeb`) which we need to import to another site in different farm. The site contains some features which are not present in destination farm. So we end up getting errors like:

> Could not find Feature < FEATURE NAME >

We don't have access on the source server so we cannot disable features on it before exporting.

Is there a way to disable the features while importing?

Comment: How did you export your site? Did you use Export-SPWeb?

Comment: @Bunzab: Yes, we used Export-SPWeb

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't use compression you can edit the Requirements.xml file and remove the unwanted features.

If you did use compression you will need to change the extension of your cmp file to cab and extract the Requirements.xml and make the same change. Unfortunately this is not an easy process if you have not rebuilt cab files before.

If you struggle with the cab you could just extract its contents to a folder, edit the xml and then when you import just point to the folder path and drop the -NoFileCompression parameter.

Comment: Is there a way to do it via powershell command parameter rather than messing around with the backup file?

Comment: No. You would need to write your own Import cmdlet.